# From Data Only generated scripts to Post Deployment Scripts. Is there a way?

Tags: sql-server, c#, rdbms

Currently, to add lookup data on post deployment scripts I'm implementing an utility that creates such post deployment scripts from inserts scripts generated by SQL Server **Generate and Publish Scripts**. Something along these lines:

```
    public void GeneratePostDeploymentScripts()
    {
        var postDeployment = new PostDeployment();

        GetInsertsFromFile(postDeployment.DataFile, postDeployment.Inserts);

        GetIdentitiesFromDataFile(postDeployment.DataFile, postDeployment.Identities);

        GetValuesFromInserts(postDeployment.Inserts, postDeployment.Values);

        GetTableFromInserts(postDeployment.Inserts, postDeployment.Tables);

        CreateInitialiseLookupSqlFiles(postDeployment.Values, postDeployment.Files);

        PopulateInitialiseLookupSqlFiles(postDeployment.Tables, postDeployment.Values, postDeployment.Files, postDeployment.Inserts, postDeployment.Identities);

        CreatePostDeploymentScript(postDeployment.Files);
    }
```

The final results are individual scripts for each table doing a `MERGE` operation on matching the `id`, `source` **no match**, and `target` **no match**.

As you may imagine, the lookup data is now versioned in source control and we can easily deploy to any environment.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Better is extremely subjective.  Is there something specific you are looking for, that this method doesn't accomplish?

Comment: Hi Max, agreed, better is subjective. In a nutshell what we need is to have post deployment scripts being generated automatically from production. Data only generated scripts are not useful for database projects as far as I know and for various reasons. I have the project available on github if you wish to take a look.

Comment: To complement, this task is a small step in automating deployment. Perhaps adding an example of pre and post results with objectives listed would be of help?